# Sub Document Indexing in MongoDB

Tags: .net, mongodb, optimization, indexing

Consider a collection of documents in MongoDB representing survey responses with a similar structure to this:

```
{
    _id: ...  
    surveryId: ...  
    created: ...  
    answers: {  
        "53ac9a031703670858aff600": "Yes",  
        "53b1e8961703670aa858e4ec": "18364537",  
        "53b1e8961703670aa858e4ee": "88422",  
        ...  
        "53b1e8961703670aa858e50a": NumberLong(2)  
    }  
}
```

Each entry in the answers subdocument represents the user's answer to an individual question on a survey and **there may be hundreds of questions on a survey**.  Additionally, the survey questions are created by the user so the keys of the answers sub document can vary from document to document (i.e. another document may not contain "53ac9a031703670858aff600").  The questions themselves are stored in a separate collection of surveys.

In order to enable fast retrieval of survey responses (i.e. Show me all survey responses where question A was answered "Yes"), I tried to add the following index:

```
db.responses.ensureIndex({"answers": 1})
```

However, when building this index I get the error "Btree::insert: key too large to index" indicating that the total size of an index entry is longer than 1024 bytes.

My question is twofold:

1. Is there a way to index the answers sub document in bulk so that I can issue a query like `db.responses.find({"answers.53ac9a031703670858aff600": "Yes"})` and that query hit an index?
2. If I cannot create a index that will cover the entire answers sub document, what are my options to ensure that any survey answer can be retrieved using an index?  Should I consider a new document design for responses?

The app accessing this data is a .NET application using the official MongoDB driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a MongoDB anti-pattern: Value-keys.

Do not use values (in this case ObjectId's from another collection) as keys of a (sub-)document.

1. It is hard to make any advanced queries on it because there are many operators which work on values but almost none which work on keys
2. it is impossible to index, because you can only create indexes on known keys.

Instead of an object with a large number of unknown fields, use an array of key-value pairs:

```
answers: [  
    { "question": "53ac9a031703670858aff600", "answer": "Yes" },
    { "question": "53b1e8961703670aa858e4ec", "answer": "18364537" },
    { "question": "53b1e8961703670aa858e4ee", "answer": "88422" },
    { "question": "53b1e8961703670aa858e50a", "answer": NumberLong(2) }
]
```

You can then create an index on `answers.question` to find any question quickly or a composite index on both fields to quickly find a specific question/answer combination. When you want to avoid duplicates, create an unique composite index combining `_id` and `answers.question`.

Comment: A note for future viewers who may be using the .NET driver as well: We had modeled the answers array as a Dictionary<string, dynamic> and were able to tell the .NET Mongo driver to serialize the contents of the answers Dictionary as shown above by using the [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)] attribute.